# Where is the permissions tab in Google play?

Tags: google-play-store, permissions

About 1 month ago Google change the layout on the Play store, at least on the web part. My question is simple. Is there any way to see what permissions an application have from a computer? You can see the permissions right before you install the app in the phone, but that isn't that effective.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you click `Install` to install the application (on the web or on the phone), you will notice a pop-up that says what permissions the app has and if you want to continue or not.

If the app is already installed, click on the `Installed` button and the permissions will appear.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without logging in?

Comment: I don't think so. May by use http://www.appbrain.com/ to see the permissions?

Comment: That's one thing I hated too about the latest changes. I completely switched to AppBrain for research (many advantages: spam filter, concerns for permissions shown, etc.), and they even offer a Playstore button for the install.